# Win32 - Make dialog require focus/action

Tags: winapi, dialog, focus, require, z-order

In Win32 programming the MessageBox function launches a dialog that requires action, you cannot give focus to another window in the application until you press 'OK'. Well I have a dialog box that I designed in the resource editor of Visual Studio 2008 and the problem is that I can click the menu-item that launches it, and while that dialog is still being showed I can click it again and show another one of them. Also I can use the rest of my application while the dialog is open.

I would like to make it so that the user must press 'OK' or 'Cancel' on my custom dialog to do anything else at all in the application, as if it were a MessageBox. How would I accomplish this? Is there a specific windows style or ex-style that I can set on my Dialog resource? I have tried WS_TOPMOST but I got no effect, I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog needs to be launched with [DialogBox().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [DialogBoxParam()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or any of the direct dialog modal launchers. Further, you need to be sure and provide the top-level window of your application as the parent window when you you call it. Doing this should make your dialog modal, rather than modeless. It is important that you also use the WS_POPUP window style for your dialog template in the resource script, but it is usually set by default, so that is likely not your problem.

Comment: Great, that's almost it. Now, I have a problem still. I have toolwindows that can float free along with my main window. When I launch my dialog now it doesn't allow me to use my main window as expected, but, I can use my toolwindow, which happens to have a button that also launches the dialog, so I can still spawn multiple instances of this dialog. Is there any possible way to make sure that no other window in my application can be used when this dialog is on the screen? BTW, these toolwindows are created with CreateDialogParam so they can be shown and hidden

Comment: All children of that main should be modal to the dialog as well. How are the tool windows setup? if they're free-floating popups with no parental relationship, that may be what you're seeing. If they're available by handle you may end up resorting to enumerating them and disabling while the dialog is up. There are other ways, but that was just off the top of my head. You mentioned they are created with CreateDialogBoxParam to allow show/hide. so.. hide before the call to DialogBox? =P

Comment: This is how I create the tool Windows. Styles/Ex-Styles: `DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` and when I use `CreateDialogParam` I set the parent to the same as I do with the `DialogBox` dialog, I set it to the handle of my main window. They are free-floating and are never destroyed until the application quits. So you are saying I can use `EnableWindow` to disable the toolwindow until `DialogBox` returns? I would prefer not to but if that is the most practical it will do.

Comment: Yeah, I tried enumerating through the toolwindows and disabling them, but when I launched my `DialogBox` it made the toolwindow not only disappear but even though I enabled the toolwindow after the `DialogBox` call it refused to ever show again, even when I clicked the menuitem that launches it.

Comment: Okay, my problem was actually with the iterator I was using to enumerate through the tool-window handles. Everything works as expected now. Thank you!